# R replace value with frequency

Tags: r

I am trying to replace the values in data frame with frequency.

Here is my data:

```
blah<-list(c(1,1,2,2,3,1,3,2,2,5,5), c(7,8,7,8,9,9,7,8,9,7,7))
blah<-as.data.frame(blah)
colnames(blah)<-c("col1","col2")
```

I have created a table with two columns.

Next, I use "table" to generate the frequency for both columns:

```
col1Freq<-table(blah[,1])/dim(blah)[1]
col2Freq<-table(blah[,2])/dim(blah)[1]
```

My goal is to replace all the values in *blah* to frequencies. So the final table should be the same size as *blah*, but I want frequencies instead of integers.

Sorry I don't have any pics to show.... Thanks for your help!!!!

Comment: +1 for the fully reproducible example.

Comment: Josh's answer is great;  I just wonder why you want to create this output matrix, seeing as it's loaded w/ redundant values? After all, you can use the values in the output of `table` , combined with the `dimnames` values for that table, to do anything you could do with the new `blah2` matrix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I correctly understand your question, the base R function `ave()` (pay no attention to its misleading name) will do what you're looking for.

```
blah2 <- 
transform(blah,
          col1Freq = ave(col1, col1, FUN=function(X) length(X)/nrow(blah)),
          col2Freq = ave(col2, col2, FUN=function(X) length(X)/nrow(blah)))

blah2[3:4]
#     col1Freq  col2Freq
# 1  0.2727273 0.4545455
# 2  0.2727273 0.2727273
# 3  0.3636364 0.4545455
# 4  0.3636364 0.2727273
# 5  0.1818182 0.2727273
# 6  0.2727273 0.2727273
# 7  0.1818182 0.4545455
# 8  0.3636364 0.2727273
# 9  0.3636364 0.2727273
# 10 0.1818182 0.4545455
# 11 0.1818182 0.4545455
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem. In my case, I need such transformation to later calculate product of frequencies for each column, which should result into frequency (probability) of multivariate (multidimensional) data.

My solution works for any number of columns:

```
apply(blah,2,function(x){
 t = as.data.frame(table(x))
 t$Freq[match(x,t[,1])]/length(x)
})
```